# Setup htaccess to redirect 5 specific pages and wildcard the rest

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have a site that is going to be removed completely.  In order to keep the URLs in check we are going to redirect them to an existing site that covers basically the same information.  We have 5 specific URLs that need directed to the new site and then any other URLs to be wildcard redirected.

Here's what I have for the htaccess.  I'm wondering if it will work this way or if there is some special way I need to specify redirections for the 5 URLs with that wildcard in place

```
Redirect 301 http://www.oldurl.com/MB http://www.newurl.com/MB
Redirect 301 http://oldurl.com/MB http://www.newurl.com/MB
```

and I have 5 of those for the redirects.  here's the Wildcard:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/*   http://www.newurl.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/MB$ http://www.newurl.com/MB
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.newurl.com/
```

in the htaccess file in your "oldurl.com" document root.

Or if you'd rather use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^MB$ http://www.newurl.com/MB [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newurl.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Quick question: this doesn't work if a user types in https:// in front of the URL.  How can I catch that traffic as well?

Comment: @FranticJ3 not sure why it wouldnt, unless the https vhost has a different document root